# c++ variadic template constructor and common constructors

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++14, variadic-templates

Code like (c++14):

```
struct S { int a; int b; };

class C
{
  public:
    C(char const*, size_t) {} // 1
    C(S const&) {} // 2
    C(S const*) {} // 3
    template<typename ...T> C(T&& ...) {} // 4

 // C(S) {} // 5
 // C(S*) {} // 6
};

S s { 1, 2 };
C c1 { s }; // calls 4 and not 2
C c2 { "abc", 3 }; // calls 4 and not 1
C c3 { (char const*)"abc", (size_t)3 }; // calls 1 - ok
C c4 { s }; // calls 5 if uncommented
C c5 { &s }; // calls 6 if uncommented
S const s2 {};
C c6 { &s2 }; // calls 3
```

Simple constructor is called if it has exact the same signature as the passed parameter.
Is there some trick to use common constructors as usual with a variadic template constructor, without copying classes, passed as parameters, and overloading constructors like:

```
C(S const*) {}
C(S*) {}
```

And without additional tags in constructors

Comment: You would like to keep both variadic templated and non templated constructor, and make sure it calls the non templated constructor first; is this correct?

Comment: What about U? It is not used, is this intentional?

Comment: The problem is that constructors with forward (universal) references "eat" anything, they are preferred over all other constructors.

Comment: @Lorenzo Belli U just shows that C is template. May be it will be semantic to solve the problem

Comment: @РоманКоптев But `C` is not a template in any of your examples.

Comment: @ Barry  you are right. I have deleted all about U, to not do the example comlicated.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a tag? Explicit is better than implicit, imo.

Comment: @ Brian I use tags, but this is a top level interface class, user API, and it's using without tags looks more natural

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create two tiers of constructor.  Then tag dispatch.

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class T>
struct is_template:std::false_type{};
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct is_template<Z, Z<Ts...>>:std::true_type{};

struct foo {
private:
  template<class T> struct tag{ explicit tag(int) {} };
public:
  foo( tag<std::true_type>, const char*, size_t );
  template<class...Ts>
  foo( tag<std::false_type>, Ts&&...ts );

public:
  foo() = default; // or whatever
  template<class T0, class...Ts,
    std::enable_if_t<!is_template<tag, std::decay_t<T0>>{},int> =0>
  foo(T0&&t0, Ts&&...ts):
    foo( tag<typename std::is_constructible< foo, tag<std::true_type>, T0&&, Ts&&... >::type>{0}, std::forward<T0>(t0), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... )
  {}
};
```

The "preferred" ctors are prefixed with `std::true_type`, the "less preferred" ctors are prefixed with `std::false_type`.

This has the usual imperfections of perfect forwarding.  If you take initializer lists, you'll want to have another "public" ctor that takes that explicitly, for example.  And function name argument magical overloading won't work.  `NULL` is an `int`.  Etc.

You can imagine a version that, instead of having two tiers, has an arbitrary number.  The `is_constructible< ... >` clause in the public facing ctor instead is replaced with some magic that finds the highest N such that `tag<N>, blah...` can construct the object (or, lowest `N`, whichever way you want to do it).  Then it returns the type `tag<N>`, which then dispatches to that tier.

Using a technique like this:

```
template <typename... T,
      typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_constructible<C, T&&...>::value>
       >
C(T&&... ) { }
```

runs into [a serious problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33040916/1774667) down the road, as we have instantiated `is_constructible` in a context where *it gets the answer wrong*.  And in practice, compilers cache the results of template instantiations, so now the result of `is_constructible` is compiler order dependent (ODR violation I suspect).

Comment: Shouldn't `is_constructible` take `<foo, true_type, T0&&, Ts&&...>`? This is brilliant, btw.

Comment: `is_constructible` is supposed to perform access checking in an unrelated context (i.e., no private ctors).

Comment: @T.C. Fixed.  Made them pseudo-private with requiring a private template to call.

Comment: @T.C. Why the addition of the `explicit` constructor taking the `int` param?

Comment: @barry I think to prevent `{}` from being able to construct the `tag`.  Now the caller has to `tag<blah>{0}`, which cannot be done outside of the class, as they cannot name the type `tag<blah>`.

Comment: @Barry what is wrong with using an `int*` instead of an `int`?  Admittedly, the `int*` is pretty pointless.  (and I might need to change `0` to `nullptr`)

Comment: @Yakk It didn't compile for me with `int*` and did with `int`, didn't actually think about how `0` is a null pointer literal and figured it was a typo at the time.

Comment: @Barry What about of constructors' and member functions' priority control without forwarding from a top level variadic-templated interface member? Something in direction of http://stackoverflow.com/a/33048151/5177149

Comment: @Yakk Could you please explain what `is_template` is used for?

Comment: @TobiasHermann It should be called `is_instance_of_template`.  It is true if and only if the 2nd argument is an instance of the 1st argument template.  Here I use it to prevent the public perfect forwarding ctor from eating `tag<?>`-tagged constructor calls.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable your variadic constructor if and only if those arguments do not allow you to construct `C` in some other way using [`std::is_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible).

That is:

```
template <typename... T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_constructible<C, T&&...>::value>
           >
C(T&&... ) { }
```

With that change, `C c1{s}` does call `(2)` and `C c2{"abc", 3}` does call `(1)`, whereas `C c7{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` will call `(4)`.

Comment: I'm slightly confused: Why doesn't this cause infinite recursive template instantiation?

Comment: @dyp I believe this constructor won't be considered until the ends of its declarator.

Comment: But that's a default template-argument, shouldn't it be instantiated later?

Comment: What about overloading of other member functions, not constructors?

Comment: Please see http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JM2U8pxxvguewhd1 For the last `int` argument, the variadic ctor should produce a better overload. When the SFINAE is deactivated, it is called indeed. So later ctors seem to be considered in this `is_constructible` check.

Comment: @dyp [Followup question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997699/fallback-variadic-constructor-why-does-this-work)

Comment: `int x = 0; C c{x}; std::cout << std::is_constructible<C, int&>{} << '\n';` [oops](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/074de74fe5e8fd86). [What goes wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33040916/1774667)

Answer (score 0):

This is another one solution that doesn't use tag dispatching. Here constructors are tested in chosen order, and may be used simple constructor with variadic-templated one without perfect forwarding from interface variadic-templated constructor. E.g. I can use constructor with std::pair parameter and in it use brace-initializer list `{ "String", 6 }` , not explicit pass `std::pair<char const*, size_t>("String", 6)` and so on, as shown in the example. This method can be used not only to control constructors' priority, but and to control priority of other members' overloading. It needs a helper class at the moment.

I'm new in different metaprogramming tricks, it's just a propose. I wont it to be improved.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Some standard-like classes:

```
struct null_helper { static constexpr int const value = 0; };

template<template<unsigned> typename Helper, unsigned order, typename ...TT>
class constructible_from_order
{
    using PrevType = typename conditional<(order < 1), null_helper,
                                           constructible_from_order<Helper, order-1, TT&&...>>::type;
    static constexpr int const prev = PrevType::value;
    static constexpr bool const is_this_constructible = is_constructible<Helper<order>, TT&&...>::value;
  public:
    static constexpr int const value = prev ? prev : is_this_constructible ? order : 0;

}; // template class constructible_from_order

template<template<unsigned> typename Helper, unsigned order, typename ...TT>
using enable_in_order = enable_if<(constructible_from_order<Helper, order, TT&&...>::value == order)>;

template<template<unsigned> typename Helper, unsigned order, typename ...TT>
using enable_in_order_t = typename enable_in_order<Helper, order, TT&&...>::type;
```

Class definition for example:

```
using blob_data = pair<char const*, size_t>;

class C {

    template<unsigned order>
    class helper
    {
      public:
        helper(char const*, size_t) {} // 1

        helper(blob_data const&, blob_data const&) {} // 1

        template<typename T, typename = enable_if_t<(order == 2) && sizeof(T)>>
        helper(blob_data const&, T&&) {} // 2

        template<typename T, typename = enable_if_t<(order == 3) && sizeof(T)>>
        helper(T&&, blob_data const&) {} // 3

        template <class... Ts, typename = enable_if_t<(order == 4) && sizeof...(Ts)>>
        helper(Ts&&... ) {} // 4

    }; // template class helper

  public: // constructors:

    // order 1
    C(char const*, size_t) { cout << "1" << endl; }

    // order 1
    C(blob_data const&, blob_data const&) { cout << "1" << endl; }

    // order 2
    template<typename T, typename = enable_in_order_t<helper, 2, blob_data const&, T&&>>
    C(blob_data const&, T&&) { cout << "2" << endl; }

    // order 3
    template<typename T, typename = enable_in_order_t<helper, 3, T&&, blob_data const&>>
    C(T&&, blob_data const&) { cout << "3" << endl; }

    // order 4
    template <class... Ts, typename = enable_in_order_t<helper, 4, Ts&&... >>
    C(Ts&&... ) { cout << "4" << endl;}

  public: // member functions:

    // order 1
    void fun(char const*, size_t) { cout << "1" << endl; }

    // order 1
    void fun(blob_data const&, blob_data const&) { cout << "1" << endl; }

    // order 2
    template<typename T, typename = enable_in_order_t<helper, 2, blob_data const&, T&&>>
    void fun(blob_data const&, T&&) { cout << "2" << endl; }

    // order 3
    template<typename T, typename = enable_in_order_t<helper, 3, T&&, blob_data const&>>
    void fun(T&&, blob_data const&) { cout << "3" << endl; }

    // order 4
    template <class... Ts, typename = enable_in_order_t<helper, 4, Ts&&... >>
    void fun(Ts&&... ) { cout << "4" << endl;}

}; // class C
```

Use as:

```
int main() {

  char const* str = "aaa";

  // constructors:
  cout << "Constructors: " << endl;
  cout << "1: "; C  c1   {        str,  size_t{5} };
  cout << "1: "; C  cx   { { str, 5 }, { str, 5 } };
  cout << "2: "; C  c2   { { str, 5 },        str };
  cout << "3: "; C  c3   {        str, { str, 5 } };
  cout << "4: "; C  c4   {        str,        str };
  cout << endl;

  // functions:
  cout << "Functions: " << endl;
  cout << "1: "; c1.fun(        str,  size_t{5} );
  cout << "1: "; c1.fun( { str, 5 }, { str, 5 } );
  cout << "2: "; c1.fun( { str, 5 },        str );
  cout << "3: "; c1.fun(        str, { str, 5 } );
  cout << "4: "; c1.fun(        str,        str );
  cout << endl;

} // main
```

Program output:

```
Constructors:
1: 1
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4

Functions: 
1: 1
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
```