# Overloading variadic-templated member function and variadic-templated functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading, variadic-templates

Is there easy way to overload variadic-templated function with a common function, like shown for constructors here [c++ variadic template constructor and common constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957830/c-variadic-template-constructor-and-common-constructors?noredirect=1#comment53741692_32957830) (c++11 - c++14)

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {};

class C
{
  public:
  void fun(S const&) { std::cout << " fun(S const& ) " << std::endl; } // 1

  template<typename ... T>
  void fun(T&&...) { std::cout << " fun(T&&...) " << std::endl; } // 2
};

int main ()
{
    S s{};
    C c{};

    c.fun(s);
    c.fun(5); // call 1 - ?
}
```

I want to do `c.fun(5)` to call non-variadic-templated version. Some solution like that was shown for constructors using `std::enable_if` and `std::is_constructible`. I need overloading on requirements

Comment: Both call #2 for me.

Comment: It's already overloaded. However, when you call `c.fun(s);` type of the argument is deduced to `S&&`. You can call overload with `c.fun((const S&) s);`.

Comment: I know it is overloaded and I can call it with a way  `c.fun((const S&) s)`, but I want to use the overloading as usual. As was shown for constructors, not variadic-templated version can be easy called before variadic-templated, using `std::enable_if` and `std::is_constructable`. Look a link. I'm searching a good solution for other members too. Something like enabling variadic-templated version if member is not callabal, but it is difficult to have the address of overloaded function.

Answer (score 1):

I have done just a workaround, not very elegant

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct S {};

class C
{
    class helper
    {
    public:
      helper(S const&) { std::cout << " fun(S const& ) " << std::endl; }

      template<typename ... T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_constructible<helper, T&&...>::value> >
      helper(T&&...) { std::cout << " fun(T&&...) " << std::endl; }
    };

  public:

  template<typename ... T>
  void fun(T&&... args) { helper { std::forward<T>(args)... }; }


};


int main ()
{
    S s{};
    C c{};

    c.fun(s);
    c.fun(5);

}
```