# Fallback variadic constructor - why does this work?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

In answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32957830/2069064) about trying to construct a variadic forwarding reference constructor that should only be called if no other constructor is valid. That is, if there was a:

```
C(const char*, size_t) { }                     // 1
template <typename... T, ???> C(T&&... ) { }   // 2
```

We'd want `C c1{"abc", 2};` to call (1), despite the required conversion, but `C c2{1, 2, 3};` to call (2), as (1) cannot apply.

I proposed the following solution:

```
template <typename... T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_constructible<C, T&&...>::value>
           >
C(T&&... ) { }
```

And by proposed, I mean, I tried it and was surprised to discover that it actually works. It compiles and does exactly what I had hoped for on both gcc and clang. However, I am at a loss to explain *why* it works or even if it's actually *supposed* to work and gcc and clang are both just being particularly accommodating. Is it? Why?

Comment: Based on my understanding if another constructor is available for `C c1{"abc", 2};` than `std::enable_if_t` will have no value, and therefore create something like `template <typename... T, typename = >` and SFINAE would not create the templated constructor.

Comment: Reposting my comment on your answer: [this modified example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JM2U8pxxvguewhd1) shows that the default argument SFINAE considers *all* constructors of `C`, even those that are declared after the constructor template.

Comment: For what little it's worth, MSVC 2013 also accepts this syntax under /W4 and prints the same thing as gcc and clang with [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fe984a4ceb6e193), though it *does* warn about multiple default constructors, and intellisense doesn't seem to think that the third call to `Foo::Foo` is valid. (Again, this is despite VC++ 18 being fine with it)

Comment: The current working draft doesn't describe when default template arguments are instantiated (see [CWG 2008](http://wg21.link/cwg2008)), so I don't really see how this question can be satisfactorily answered.

Comment: This isn't the only problem with `is_constructible` + default function/template arguments. See, e.g., [LWG 2452](http://wg21.link/lwg2452).

Comment: @T.C. I sure know how to pick 'em. Sounds like some combination of that is an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue with your code is that we just instantiated `is_constructible` in a context where *it gets the answer wrong*.  Any kind of caching in the template code is likely to result in bugs -- try printing `is_constructible` on the same parameters after you call the constructor!  It is likely to get it wrong.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/074de74fe5e8fd86) of how it can go wrong.  Notice it claims `C` cannot be constructed from an `int&`, despite having done so on the previous line.

```
struct C {
  C(const char*, size_t) {}
  template <class... Ts,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_constructible<C, Ts&&...>::value>
  >
  C(Ts&&... ) { }
};

int main() {
  int a = 0;
  C x{a};
  std::cout << std::is_constructible<C, int&>{} << '\n';
}
```

oops.

I suspect this might be an ODR violation -- the two definitions of `is_constructible` have different types at different spots?  Or maybe not.

[Solution to the original problem that does not have this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33041242/1774667) also posted.

Comment: @dyp possibly.  I was just pointing out that the solution presented doesn't actually work.  I guess I went off and solved the original problem as well.  ;)  Ok, split it into two parts.

Comment: Where does the Standard specify the point of instantiation of template default-arguments? T.C. seems to imply in the comments to the OP that this is underspecified..

Comment: @dyp Sure, I can believe lots of things are under-specified in the standard.  So either it doesn't work (because it is instantiated late enough to see itself?), or it works (and breaks the world, as it gets the wrong answer)?  My point is that relying on `is_constructible` to get the wrong answer is not a solution, but a problem hiding in the guise of a solution.

Comment: Not sure I understand your point: `is_constructible` works in the way Barry expected it; it seems to be instantiated late (gets the right answer) but doesn't cause infinite recursion by re-instantiating the constructor template it is part of. I'm not sure if it's allowed to get the wrong answer, nor am I sure if it's allowed to break because of infinite recursion (but I guess both are underspecified).

Comment: "I can be constructed from every set of types I can't be constructed from" is simply paradoxical. I can definitely see it being made ill-formed NDR.

Comment: @T.C. Hmm, good point, I missed that it was a paradox in my previous comments, and was thinking "if only the compiler cheated and got the right answer, everything would be ok".  But there is no way for everything to be ok sometimes.  I blame Russell.

Comment: @Yakk This technique does see constructors declared *after* this weird constructor template, see my comment to the OP. Also, the default template argument can only be instantiated *after* the class template has been instantiated, AFAIK. It needs the function/constructor argument types, for example.

Comment: @Yakk Why does `is_constructible<>` get the wrong answer for my approach?

Comment: @Barry I don't know why it does technically; in practice, because it cannot give the answer false and it be the right answer: if it returns false, you define a constructor that can construct using those exact same arguments. Which means that it was the wrong answer. Now, if it then returned true, you would no longer define that constructor, and without another one to back it up, it would also be wrong. You have encoded "this constructor exists if it does not exist". The standard could mandate that your program is ill-formed, or it could mandate that `is_constructible` gets the wrong answer.

Comment: @Barry There are arguments that the answer is "the standard doesn't specify well enough what should happen", but that is beyond my standard-delving abilities.  My answer tries to demonstrate "there is no good answer here for the standard to mandate", not what the standard states happens.

Comment: @Yakk That makes sense to me.