# Visibility of member functions in a CRTP class

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++14, crtp

I am writing a sorting library with sorter function objects. One of the main classes, `sorter_facade`, is intended to provide some overloads of `operator()` to the sorter depending on the overloads that already exist. Here is a simple reduced example of a `heap_sorter` object, implementing a heapsort:

```
struct heap_sorter:
    sorter_facade<heap_sorter>
{
    using sorter_facade<heap_sorter>::operator();

    template<typename Iterator>
    auto operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last) const
        -> void
    {
        std::make_heap(first, last);
        std::sort_heap(first, last);
    }
};
```

One of the simplest goals of `sorter_facade` is to provide an iterable overload to the sorter's `operator()` when an overload taking a pair of iterators already exists. Here is a reduced implementation of `sorter_facade`, sufficient for the problem at hand:

```
template<typename Sorter>
struct sorter_facade
{
    template<typename Iterable>
    auto operator()(Iterable& iterable) const
        -> std::enable_if_t<
            not has_sort<Sorter, Iterable>,
            decltype(std::declval<Sorter&>()(std::begin(iterable), std::end(iterable)))
        >
    {
        return Sorter{}(std::begin(iterable), std::end(iterable));
    }
};
```

In this class, `has_sort` is a trait used to detect whether a sorter has an `operator()` overload taking an `Iterable&`. It is implemented using a hand-rolled version of the [detection idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected):

```
template<typename Sorter, typename Iterable>
using has_sort_t = std::result_of_t<Sorter(Iterable&)>;

template<typename Sorter, typename Iterable>
constexpr bool has_sort = std::experimental::is_detected_v<has_sort_t, Sorter, Iterable>;
```

---

Now, to the actual problem: the following `main` works well with g++ 5.2:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec(3);
    heap_sorter{}(vec);
}
```

However, [it fails with clang++ 3.7.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b165f2e26b2720a), with the following error message:

> ```
> main.cpp:87:5: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'heap_sorter'
>     heap_sorter{}(vec);
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/../../../../include/c++/5.2.0/type_traits:2388:44: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with Iterable = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]
>     using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
>                                            ^
>
> main.cpp:75:10: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
>     auto operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last) const
>      ^
>
> 1 error generated.
> ```

Apparently, when evaluating the `std::enable_if_t`, it seems to consider that `Sorter` already has an `operator()` able to take an `Iterable&`, which probably means that clang++ and g++ do not valuate the "same" `Sorter` when checking for the existence of the overload.

For this simple example, removing the `std::enable_if_t` makes the whole thing work, but the class `sorter_facade` is actually much bigger than that and I need it to resolve ambiguity problems with other overloads of `operator()`, so just removing it isn't a solution.

So... what causes the error? Should compilers accept or reject this code? Finally, is there a standard-compatible way to make this work with the latest versions of g++ and clang++?

---

**EDIT:** as a side note, I managed to get all the crazy to work with both g++5 and clang++3.8 by adding another layer of *black magic* to the point I've no idea why it even works anymore at all. While of all the previous questions hold, here is the « workaround » (using C++17 `std::void_t`):

```
tempate<typename Sorter>
struct wrapper:
    Sorter
{
#ifdef __clang__
    using Sorter::operator();

    template<typename Iterable>
    auto operator()(Iterable& iterable) const
        -> std::enable_if_t<false, std::void_t<Iterable>>
    {}
#endif
};

template<typename Sorter>
struct sorter_facade
{
    template<typename Iterable>
    auto operator()(Iterable& iterable) const
        -> std::enable_if_t<
            not has_sort<wrapper<Sorter>, Iterable>,
            decltype(std::declval<Sorter&>()(std::begin(iterable), std::end(iterable)))
        >
    {
        return Sorter{}(std::begin(iterable), std::end(iterable));
    }
};
```

I guess that it abuses different compiler-specific behaviours in both g++ and clang++ and achieves something that wasn't meant to work, but still... I'm amazed that it works, even in my whole project, which has many more tricky things to handle...

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but what does `not has_sort<Sorter, Iterable>` mean in a template? I mean, I know what *not* means in English as well as what's *has_sort*, but is it a legal statement as a template argument? I've never had seen it before, I'm curious.

Comment: @skypjack Interestingly enough, [`not` is a synonym for `!` in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical)

Comment: @jaggedSpire :-D Was simply that? So much time has passed since the last time I've seen it that I even forgot that it exists!! Shame of me. :-) ... I thought about some keyword related only to templates and completely missed the point. Thank you. I'm going to change job right now.

Comment: @skypjack It's an oft-forgotten corner of the language, to be sure. I wouldn't quit over it though-if you quit now you can't take advantage of knowing it. ;)

Comment: I don't know whether there is any rule that covers such "self-referencing" function templates. But I'm inclined to say that this is undefined behavior. It even gives me trouble thinking about how GCC may have interpreted this. Can you explain?

Comment: @ᐅJohannesSchaub-litbᐊ If only... It seems that g++ knows more about `Sorter` than the mere fact that it exists by the time it instantiates the functions in the `sorter_facade`. On the other hand, I already had other similar but different problems showing that g++ and clang++ probably do not try to infer things about functions at the same time.

Comment: Looks like another "I exist if I don't exist" thing. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997699/fallback-variadic-constructor-why-does-this-work

Comment: @T.C. Looks more or less like it's that. It's a pain, half of the library's design relies on that .____.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this is a bug in clang. The return type of `sorter_facade<Sorter>::operator()` depends on the template argument Iterator. Still, the compiler seems to decide to SFINAE out before knowing the arguments.

But bug or not, you can work around this by explicitly deferring the calculation of the return type. Here is a version that does not depend on black magic. Works with gcc-5.2 and clang-3.6:

```
template<typename Sorter, typename Iterable>
struct sort_result
{
  using type =  decltype(
      std::declval<Sorter&>()(
         std::begin(std::declval<Iterable&>()),
         std::end(std::declval<Iterable&>())));
};

template<typename Sorter, typename Deferred>
using sort_result_t = typename sort_result<Sorter, Deferred>::type;

template<typename Sorter>
struct sorter_facade
{
  template <typename Iterable>
  auto operator()(Iterable& iterable) const
      -> sort_result_t<Sorter, Iterable>
    {
        return Sorter{}(std::begin(iterable), std::end(iterable));
    }
};

struct heap_sorter:
    sorter_facade<heap_sorter>
{
    using sorter_facade<heap_sorter>::operator();

    template<typename Iterator>
    auto operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last) const
        -> void
    {
        std::make_heap(first, last);
        std::sort_heap(first, last);
    }
};

int main()
{
      std::vector<int> vec(3);
          heap_sorter{}(vec);
}
```

The trick is: The compiler does not know if you specialize the result_type later on. Therefore it has to wait until you actually use it, before trying to determine the return type.