# How to enable a constructor template only if no other conversion is available?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, c++17, type-traits

The following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct bar {
    bar(const bar<T>&) {
        std::cout << "copy ctor\n";
    }

    template <typename U,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible_v<U, bar<T>>>>
    bar(U&&) {
        std::cout << "ctor template\n";
    }
};

struct foo {
    operator bar<int>() const {
        return bar<int>( 1 );
    }
    operator int() const {
        return 2;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo my_foo;

    std::cout << "constructor: ";
    bar<int> my_bar( my_foo );

    std::cout << "static_cast: ";
    my_bar = static_cast<bar<int>>(my_foo);
}
```

[produces](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8Lmaqp2oX69U6dEb)

```
constructor: ctor template
static_cast: ctor template
```

as output.

However I would like the constructor template of bar, i.e. `template <typename U> bar::bar(U&&)`, to only be enabled if `U` is not already convertible to `bar<T>`. In case of `foo` such a conversion is already given with `foo::operator bar<int>() const`. Let's assume I am the author of `bar` and have no knowledge about (or influence on) `foo` or possible similar classes. How can I convince the compiler to use the conversion operator in that situation without removing `bar`'s ctor template completely?

Comment: If the number of constructors is relatively small, define a helper class with those constructors, then use a stock SFINAE approach to see if the helper class can be constructed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks, that is a very nice idea. However in my case I can control and change `bar` but have no knowledge or influence on `foo` and similar classes. I just added this assumption to my question.

Comment: In the second case, with `static_cast`, `"ctor template"` is printed by `bar<int>( 1 )`. Seems working as intended.

Comment: Try putting print statements in your `foo` conversion operators and rerun your test.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: In case you are using GCC, it has a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81952) that causes this behavior.

Comment: @TobiasHermann I don't think that bug applies here. `bar<int>( 1 )`  has no choice but to call template constructor; and then returning this temporary by value has every right to elide copy constructor. And, I get the same output [with clang](http://rextester.com/IAQ32605)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Sorry, I misread your comment. You are right of course. However I still would like the copy ctor to be used, probably by disabling the ctor template.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: This is a very good suggestion. Thank you. I just added it to my code.

Comment: The copy ctor is chosen but elided.

Comment: The copy constructor **is** used for copying `bar<int>` around (though often elided). It cannot possibly be used for constructing `bar<int>` from `1`. I'm not sure I understand what you expect to happen differently.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: `foo::operator bar<int>() const` seems to be called and thus I would like the copy ctor of bar to be used if possible.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Why is the copy ctor elided?

Comment: Because the c++ standard allows it.  Try compiling with `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Comment: Howard beat me to it. Output is as expected when you turn off elision: [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mcC8mQl1Z4QwjMcb)

Comment: Before a copy constructor can be used, there must be an instance of `bar` to be copied. How is *that* instance going to be constructed, if not by the template constructor? You seem to expect an instance of `bar<int>` to magically materialize out of thin air, to be copied shortly afterwards.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I expected an instance of `bar<int>` to be created by `foo::operator bar<int>() const`. But of course, this does use `bar`'s ctor template. I foolishly overlooked this. Thank you. I will refine my question soon.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Ah, thanks. Now I understand what you meant. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it seems to already be doing what I want. I just had to add more print statements to see it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct bar {
    bar(const bar<T>&) {
        std::cout << "copy ctor\n";
    }
    template <typename U = T,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible_v<U, bar<T>>>>
    bar(U&& val) {
        std::cout << "ctor template: " << val << "\n";
    }
};

struct foo {
    operator bar<int>() const {
        std::cout << "operator bar<int>() -> ";
        return bar<int>( 1 );
    }
    operator int() const {
        std::cout << "operator int() -> ";
        return 2;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo my_foo;

    std::cout << "constructor: ";
    bar<int> my_opt( my_foo );

    std::cout << "static_cast: ";
    my_opt = static_cast<bar<int>>(my_foo);
}
```

[outputs](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iSna3iWVKMcCqjxh)

```
constructor: operator optional<int>() -> ctor template: 1
static_cast: operator optional<int>() -> ctor template: 1
```

the copy ctor does not appear in the output because of return value optimization.

edit: As Barry pointed out in the comment, **this only works by accident and can [lead to serious problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997699/fallback-variadic-constructor-why-does-this-work).**

Comment: This doesn't actually work- see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32997699/2069064)