# Use sfinae to single out preferred variadic constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, constructor-overloading

I'm trying to write a policy-based class that forwards arguments to its unique super class, but also optionally takes some arguments of its own. The problem I'm facing is, the compiler seems to unconditionally prefer the second constructor below in the face of an implicit conversion - with only the parameter pack - over the first, which is the one I prefer.

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <class Super>
struct Base : public Super {
  // 1
  template <typename... Args,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Super, Args&&...>>>
  explicit Base(unsigned long count, Args&&... args)
    : Super(std::forward<Args>(args)...), count(count) {}

  // 2
  template <typename... Args,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Super, Args&&...>>>
  explicit Base(Args&&... args) : Super(std::forward<Args>(args)...), count(0) {}

  unsigned long count;
};

struct A {
  explicit A(unsigned long id) {}
  A() {}
};

struct B {
  explicit B(const char* cstring) {}
  explicit B(unsigned long id, const char* cstring) {}
  explicit B(unsigned long id, A a) {}
  B() {}
};

int main() {
  auto a1 = Base<A>(7);             // selects 2, but I want 1
  auto a2 = Base<A>(7ul);           // selects 1
  auto a3 = Base<A>(7, 10);         // selects 1
  auto b1 = Base<B>(4);             // selects 1
  auto b2 = Base<B>("0440");        // selects 2
  auto b3 = Base<B>(4, "0440");     // selects 2, but I want 1
  auto b4 = Base<B>(4, 4, "0440");  // selects 1
  auto b5 = Base<B>(4, A());        // selects 2
  std::printf("%lu %lu %lu\n", a1.count, a2.count, a3.count);
  std::printf("%lu %lu %lu %lu %lu\n", b1.count, b2.count, b3.count, b4.count, b5.count);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is `0 7 7` on the first line, but I want `7 7 7`, i.e. `Base<A>(7)` should select the first constructor, not the second. Idem for `b3`.

The sfinae on the constructors let the compiler choose 1 when 2 doesn't match the arguments, but I want it to select constructor 1 every time it matches. In the `a1` case, the implicit conversion of 7 from `int` to `unsigned long` is forcing a choice of constructor 2, which I also don't understand why.

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: I think [Yakk's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33041242/2069064) is probably want you want. Probably enough so that it could conceivably be considered a dupe?

Comment: @Barry looks like a valid solution indeed, will look into it, thanks!

Comment: @Barry It's a valid solution if the first argument being convertible to `unsigned long` means it cannot be the first argument to `Super`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's collect requirements:

1. First argument implicitly convertible to `unsigned long`, rest can construct base => do that.
2. Does not fit 1, and arguments can construct base => do that.

```
struct Base : Super {
    // This one should be preferred:
    template <class... Args, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Super, Args...>>>
    explicit Base(unsigned long count = 0, Args&&... args)
    : Super(std::forward<Args>(args))
    , count(count) {
    }

    // Only if the first is non-viable:
    template <class U, class... Args, class = std::enable_if_t<
        !(std::is_convertible_v<U, unsigned long> && std::is_constructible_v<Super, Args...>)
        && std::is_constructible_v<Super, U, Args>>>
    explicit Base(U&& u, Args&&... args)
    : Base(0, std::forward<U>(u), std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
    }
    unsigned long count;
};
```

Beware that both templated ctors are candidates for implicit conversions. Putting `explicit` where needed left as an exercise for the reader.

If there were more alternatives to be considered, tag-dispatching would be advisable:

```
template <std::size_t N> struct priority : priority<N - 1> {};
template <> struct priority<0> {};

template <class... Ts>
static constexpr bool has_priority_v = (std::is_base_of_v<priority<0>, std::decay_t<Ts>> || ...);

class Base : Super {
    template <class UL, class... Ts, class = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_convertible_v<UL, unsigned long> && std::is_constructible_v<Super, Ts...>>>
    Base(priority<1>, UL&& count, Ts&&... ts)
    : Super(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...), count(count)
    {}

    template <class... Ts, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Super, Ts...>>>
    Base(priority<0>, Ts&&... ts)
    : Base(priority<1>(), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
    {}
public:
    template <class... Ts, class = std::enable_if_t<
        !has_priority<Ts...> && std::is_constructible_v<Base, priority<>, Ts...>>>
    explicit Base(Ts&&... ts)
    : Base(priority<1>(), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
    {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want (though comments below point to it maybe being an invalid construct):

```
struct Base : public Super {
  // 1
  template <typename... Args,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Super, Args...>>>
  explicit Base(unsigned long count, Args&&... args)
    : Super(std::forward<Args&&>(args)...), count(count) {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<Super*, void>);
    }

  // 2
  template <typename... Args,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_constructible_v<Base, Args...>>>
  explicit Base(Args&&... args) : Super(std::forward<Args>(args)...), count(0) {}

  unsigned long count;
};
```

I love godbolt running your code now!

https://godbolt.org/z/UEweak

Comment: Doesn't `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_constructible_v<Base, Args...>>` read as enable only if not constructable from the supplied types?  Isn't that a paradox?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997699/fallback-variadic-constructor-why-does-this-work) seems to point to it being ill-formed, NDR

Comment: Ok, I'd believe that, but it does work with all three major compilers.   I have no further comments on the goodness of my solution and do not claim that it is "good".   Edited 'answer' to point out possible foibles.